# TextArea Wrapping, Consistent Implementation w/out JS

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have a textarea being rendered from a C# server control. The markup looks like the following:

```
<tr>
<td>
<span style="font-size:11pt;font-weight:bold;">Description</span>
<br>
<textarea name="Field_Description" rows="2" cols="20" id="Field_Description" style="width:300px;">
</textarea>
</td>
</tr>
```

I tried to set the wrap attribute, but this has no effect:

```html
<textarea name="IssueDescription" rows="2" cols="20" id="Field_IssueDescription" wrap="hard" style="width:300px;">
```

I have also tried `white-space : normal` in the style, this has no effect.

How does one implement wrapping for a textarea?

Comment: it wraps the text, i have checked it is working, what you are facing ?

Comment: it continues one one line in IE9 regardless of characters typed

Comment: Have you tried `overflow:scroll` css there! or textarea { white-space: pre-wrap; }

Comment: The code posted does not reproduce the issue. The text wraps in IE even without any `wrap` attribute. Either you use “wrapping” in a special sense (please explain in directly observable terms what you mean) or there is some CSS or JavaScript that causes the problem.